# Large csv in R (sqldf)

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to run some data manipulation functions on a large csv (~90GB) using the `read.csv.sql` function from the `sqldf` package

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql('/data/test.csv', 
         sql = "select count(*) from file"
         )
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip) : 
  RS_sqlite_import: /data/test.csv line 570764 expected 383 columns of data but found 384
```

I have already identified that one of my string variables has commas on some cells.

I would like to know  a more appropriate way to use the read.csv.sql function in my database, since I don't have the computational capacity to open csv completely in R.

Comment: I wonder (without much confidence) if https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/45 is relevant.

Comment: Check out the `vroom` and the function `readr::read_delim_chunked` with the latter it is possible to read the file in chunks and write them into a DB. This is handy, when the file is  really large. If you can change the format of the csv I would advise to either quote character strings or use a different field separator.

Comment: You may also try `arrow::read_csv_arrow` (https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/6e3f26af658bfca602e711ea326f1985b62bca1d/r/vignettes/arrow.Rmd)

Comment: @r2evans, Regarding issue #45, which is now closed, read.csv.sql is working again if you use the latesst version of all packages. Note that this problem was due to changes in a package that sqldf depends on.  There is no change in sqldf itself.

Comment: ph_9933, can you still reproduce the problem? I wonder if updating your installation of `RSQLite` (and possibly `sqldf`) will fix the issue.